# Загрузить плагин на Intellij IDEA с диска

Tags: golang, intellij-idea, плагин

Как установить с диска плагин golang версии 9.16  к Intellij IDEA , где убрана проблема с переменными окружения, с https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin.
Работаю сейчас под Win7 Idea Community Edition, последняя версия. Я не понимаю, как сделать из архива с github архив с плагином .zip или .jar. Если есть мысли по этому поводу, подскажите, пожалуйста.
**update:** Нашёл в описании, как собирать плагин под ubuntu или mac os, но на данный момент нету возможности работать на этих ос. Есть варианты сборки под Windows?

Comment: Там, где список плагинов, есть две кнопки - установка из репозитория и с внешнего носителя.

Comment: Буду ждать официального обновления с репозитория.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Научился работать с github и нашёл замечательную ссылку release, где всё собрано..

Answer (score 0):

Этот плагин работает только на Idea 14.1 и выше (community версия тоже поддерживается)
На https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin#pre-release-builds написано как поставить из репозитория